# Adding framework 3.5 to Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-framework-version

The title says pretty much all I am trying to achieve. Is there a way to add Framework 3.5 to Visual Studio 2013 Express?
The framework is installed on my machine. I am running windows 8.1 (if relevant). In New Project screen, under frameworks
combo box there is no option New Framework like in Visual Studio that is not express edition.

Comment: Exact same problem here and was about to ask the same question.  I am on Windows 7 Pro.